# Optimizing an algorithm java

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix

Hi I have the following method. What it does is it finds all the possible paths from the top left to bottom right of a N x M matrix. I was wondering what is the best way to optimize it for speed as it is a little slow right now. The resulted paths are then stored in a set.

**EDIT** I forgot to clarify you can only move down or right to an adjacent spot, no diagonals from your current position

```
For example
ABC
DEF
GHI
```

A path from the top left to bottom right would be ADEFI

```
static public void printPaths (String tempString, int i, int j, int m, int n, char [][] arr, HashSet<String> palindrome) {
    String newString = tempString + arr[i][j];
    if (i == m -1 && j == n-1) {
        palindrome.add(newString);
        return;
    }
    //right
    if (j+1 < n) {
        printPaths (newString, i, j+1, m, n, arr, palindrome);
    }
    //down
    if (i+1 < m) {
        printPaths (newString, i+1, j, m, n, arr, palindrome);          
    }
}
```

**EDIT** Here is the entirety of the code

```
public class palpath {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("palpath.in"));
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("palpath.out")));
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());

        int d = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());


        char[][] grid = new char [d][d];

        String index = null;

        for(int i = 0; i < d; i++)
        {
            String temp = br.readLine();
            index = index + temp;
            for(int j = 0; j < d; j++)
            {
                grid[i][j] = temp.charAt(j);
            }
        }

        br.close();

        int counter = 0;

        HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
        printPaths ("", 0, 0, grid.length, grid[0].length, grid, set);

        Iterator<String> it = set.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()){
            String temp =  it.next();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(temp).reverse();
            if(temp.equals(sb.toString()))  {
                counter++;
            }

        }




        pw.println(counter);
        pw.close();

    }


        static public void printPaths (String tempString, int i, int j, int m, int n, char [][] arr, HashSet<String> palindrome) {
            String newString = tempString + arr[i][j];
            if (i == m -1 && j == n-1) {
                palindrome.add(newString);
                return;
            }
            //right
            if (j+1 < n) {
                printPaths (newString, i, j+1, m, n, arr, palindrome);
            }
            //down
            if (i+1 < m) {
                printPaths (newString, i+1, j, m, n, arr, palindrome);          
            }
        }
```

Comment: Really *all paths*? Because in my mind that includes loops and detours.

Comment: That isn't enought code usually that isn't the problem either, show us all the code.

Comment: I forgot to clarify you can only move down or right to an adjacent spot, no diagonals from your current position

Comment: From your code it seems you are only interested in paths that go either to right or down. Either the code or the question is wrong. Please clarify!

Comment: As per my understanding you are trying to sort the matrix. Why dont you try heapsort as it has the least complexity.

Comment: for one your loops could be much more effiecient, to help we need all your code because showing one method without the loops wont help.

Comment: what do you mean really slow like does it finish eventually?

Comment: It finishes it just takes longer than I expected too.

Comment: Shall we consider the name `palindrome` meaningful? As far as I get your description you do not build nor search any palindromes...

Comment: There's exponentially many paths, so if you need them all in a set or printed out, it's going to take a long time. Are you sure you don't just need to count them?

Comment: I need to print them out since I then have to find the paths that are palindromes

Comment: The number of such paths is `Choose(n+m,n)` An easy way to create all of them is create all binary vectors of size `n+m`, with exactly `n` 1's, and then transform each of them to a series of `D`/`R` moves.

Comment: @amit Indeed. That ended up being my answer. :)

Answer (score 3):

Given a graph of length M x N, all paths from (0,0) to (M-1, N-1) that only involve rightward and downward moves are guaranteed to contain exactly M-1 moves rightward and N-1 moves downward.

This presents us with an interesting property: we can represent a path from (0,0) to (M-1, N-1) as a binary string (0 indicating a rightward move and 1 indicating a downward move).

So, the question becomes: how fast can we print out a list of permutations of that bit string?

Pretty fast.

```
public static void printPaths(char[][] arr) {
    /* Get Smallest Bitstring (e.g. 0000...111) */
    long current = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
        current <<= 1;
        current |= 1;
    }

    /* Get Largest Bitstring (e.g. 111...0000) */
    long last = current;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr[0].length - 1; i++) {
        last <<= 1;
    }

    while (current <= last) {
        /* Print Path */
        int x = 0, y = 0;
        long tmp = current;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(arr.length + arr[0].length);
        while (x < arr.length && y < arr[0].length) {
            sb.append(arr[x][y]);
            if ((tmp & 1) == 1) {
                x++;
            } else {
                y++;
            }
            tmp >>= 1;
        }
        System.out.println(sb.toString());

        /* Get Next Permutation */
        tmp = (current | (current - 1)) + 1;
        current = tmp | ((((tmp & -tmp) / (current & -current)) >> 1) - 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You spend a lot of time on string memory management.
Are strings in Java mutable? If you can change chars inside string, then set length of string as n+m, and use this the only string, setting (i+j)th char at every iteration. If they are not mutable, use array of char or something similar, and transform it to string at the end

Comment: Strings in Java are indeed immutable. You can use char[] or StringBuilder to reduce the number of String allocations as each string concatenation effectively constructs one or more new objects. That said I haven't really looked at your algorithm long enough to deduce if String handling is in fact your problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

For a given size N×M of the array *all* your paths have N+M+1 items (N+M steps), so the first step of optimization is getting rid of recursion, allocating an array and running the recursion with `while` on explicit stack.

Each partial path can be extended with one or two steps: right or down. So you can easily make an explicit stack with positions visited and a step taken on each position. Put the position (0,0) to the stack with phase (step taken) 'none', then:

```
while stack not empty {
    if stack is full /* reached lower-right corner, path complete */ {
        print the path;
        pop;
    }
    else if stack.top.phase == none {
        stack.top.phase = right;
        try push right-neighbor with phase none;
    }
    else if stack.top.phase == right {
        stack.top.phase = down;
        try push down-neighbor with phase none;
    }
    else /* stack.top.phase == down */ {
        pop;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean. Could you explain it a little more?

Answer (score 0):

If you make a few observations about your requirements you can optimise this drastically.

1. There will be exactly (r-1)+(c-1) steps (where r = rows and c = columns).
2. There will be exactly (c-1) steps to the right and (r-1) steps down.

You therefore can use numbers where a zero bit could (arbitrarily) indicate a down step while a 1 bit steps across. We can then merely iterate over all numbers of (r-1)+(c-1) bits containing just (c-1) bits set. There's a good algorithm for that at the Stanford BitTwiddling site [Compute the lexicographically next bit permutation](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#NextBitPermutation).

First a `BitPatternIterator` I have used before. You could pull out the code in `hasNext` if you wish.

```
/**
 * Iterates all bit patterns containing the specified number of bits.
 *
 * See "Compute the lexicographically next bit permutation" http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#NextBitPermutation
 *
 * @author OldCurmudgeon
 */
public static class BitPattern implements Iterable<BigInteger> {

    // Useful stuff.
    private static final BigInteger ONE = BigInteger.ONE;
    private static final BigInteger TWO = ONE.add(ONE);
    // How many bits to work with.
    private final int bits;
    // Value to stop at. 2^max_bits.
    private final BigInteger stop;

    // All patterns of that many bits up to the specified number of bits.
    public BitPattern(int bits, int max) {
        this.bits = bits;
        this.stop = TWO.pow(max);
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<BigInteger> iterator() {
        return new BitPatternIterator();
    }

    /*
     * From the link:
     *
     * Suppose we have a pattern of N bits set to 1 in an integer and
     * we want the next permutation of N 1 bits in a lexicographical sense.
     *
     * For example, if N is 3 and the bit pattern is 00010011, the next patterns would be
     * 00010101, 00010110, 00011001,
     * 00011010, 00011100, 00100011,
     * and so forth.
     *
     * The following is a fast way to compute the next permutation.
     */
    private class BitPatternIterator implements Iterator<BigInteger> {

        // Next to deliver - initially 2^n - 1 - i.e. first n bits set to 1.
        BigInteger next = TWO.pow(bits).subtract(ONE);
        // The last one we delivered.
        BigInteger last;

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            if (next == null) {
                // Next one!
                // t gets v's least significant 0 bits set to 1
                // unsigned int t = v | (v - 1);
                BigInteger t = last.or(last.subtract(BigInteger.ONE));
                // Silly optimisation.
                BigInteger notT = t.not();
                // Next set to 1 the most significant bit to change,
                // set to 0 the least significant ones, and add the necessary 1 bits.
                // w = (t + 1) | (((~t & -~t) - 1) >> (__builtin_ctz(v) + 1));
                // The __builtin_ctz(v) GNU C compiler intrinsic for x86 CPUs returns the number of trailing zeros.
                next = t.add(ONE).or(notT.and(notT.negate()).subtract(ONE).shiftRight(last.getLowestSetBit() + 1));
                if (next.compareTo(stop) >= 0) {
                    // Dont go there.
                    next = null;
                }
            }
            return next != null;
        }

        @Override
        public BigInteger next() {
            last = hasNext() ? next : null;
            next = null;
            return last;
        }

        @Override
        public void remove() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported.");
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return next != null ? next.toString(2) : last != null ? last.toString(2) : "";
        }

    }

}
```

Using that to iterate your solution:

```
public void allRoutes(char[][] grid) {
    int rows = grid.length;
    int cols = grid[0].length;
    BitPattern p = new BitPattern(rows - 1, cols + rows - 2);
    for (BigInteger b : p) {
        //System.out.println(b.toString(2));
        /**
         * Walk all bits, taking a step right/down depending on it's set/clear.
         */
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(rows + cols);
        for (int i = 0; i < rows + cols - 2; i++) {
            s.append(grid[y][x]);
            if (b.testBit(i)) {
                y += 1;
            } else {
                x += 1;
            }
        }
        s.append(grid[y][x]);
        // That's a solution.
        System.out.println("\t" + s);
    }
}

public void test() {
    char[][] grid = {{'A', 'B', 'C'}, {'D', 'E', 'F'}, {'G', 'H', 'I'}};
    allRoutes(grid);
    char[][] grid2 = {{'A', 'B', 'C'}, {'D', 'E', 'F'}, {'G', 'H', 'I'}, {'J', 'K', 'L'}};
    allRoutes(grid2);
}
```

printing

```
ADGHI
ADEHI
ABEHI
ADEFI
ABEFI
ABCFI
ADGJKL
ADGHKL
ADEHKL
ABEHKL
ADGHIL
ADEHIL
ABEHIL
ADEFIL
ABEFIL
ABCFIL
```

which - to my mind - looks right.